# Doctrine Query Builder escape percent sign

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I need to match a MySQL row that contains only % in one column, using Symfony's Query Builder. The problem is that using `setParameter('name', '%')` matches every row. How do you escape reserved words or characters?

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('u')
    ->from('Namespace:Entity', 'u')
    ->where('u.name like :name escape %');
```

Answer (score 1):

Backslash is generally the escape character in MySQL, so `` `\%' ``.

[More info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html)

EDIT: You'll have to escape the backslash in php, so actually `'\\%'`